# unknown keyword project_id in Google Cloud Dns for ruby

Tags: ruby, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to call DNS from [Google Cloud Ruby](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-ruby/tree/master/google-cloud-dns)

```
dns = Google::Cloud::Dns.new project_id: "my-id", credentials: "my_credentials"
```

but I receive this error:

```
 unknown keywords: project_id, credentials
```

how can i configure google cloud ruby DNS from code (not environment vars)

Answer (score 3):

I was running into this error message when using Google::Cloud::Storage. For some reason, the [google-cloud-storage](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-ruby/tree/master/google-cloud-storage) github page did not have the correct syntax. The [google docs](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production) have the answer:

```
storage = Google::Cloud::Storage.new(
  project: "project-123",
  keyfile: "keyfile.json
)
```

So perhaps it's a similar change for DNS.